# MySQL Select SUM JOIN WHERE together not working

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum, where-clause

I have a problem. (SQL begginer). I have two tables.

Players(nr, player_id, team_id, name, points, season)

Teams (team_id, team_name, season) - Ther is one unique team_id but the team_name can be different according to different season.

I want to SUM all points of single player_id in specific season, and I can do that :)

```
    SELECT SUM(players.points), 
           players.player_id, 
           players.team_id, 
           players.season,
           players.nr, 
           players.name 
      FROM players 
     WHERE season='2015/2016' 
  GROUP BY player_id 
  ORDER BY SUM(players.points) DESC 
     LIMIT 30
```

and this work perfect for me :) But, I can't figure it how to JOIN teams table to get 
`teams.team_name` coresponding to the specific season matched the WHERE clousure. In this case season='2015/2016' To be specyfic. If I want to sum points of players from 2015/2016 and I need to get team_name also from seasson 2015/2016. I tryed LEFT JOIN but without succeed :/
here's my code.

```
    SELECT players.player_id, 
           players.nr, 
           players.name, 
           players.team_id, 
           SUM(players.points), 
           players.season 
      FROM players 
     WHERE players.sezon='2015/2016' 
 LEFT JOIN teams 
        ON (teams.team_id=players.team_id AND teams.season=players.season ) 
  GROUP BY player_id 
  ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC 
     LIMIT 30
```

Thanks for your's effort.

Comment: I assume `players.season` vs `players.sezon` is just a copy/paste error here?

Comment: Yes. Using english words in my example. teams.season= players.season

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display players records without matching team record use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT players.player_id, 
       players.nr, 
       players.name, 
       players.team_id, 
       SUM(players.points), 
       players.season,
       teams.team_name
FROM players 
LEFT JOIN teams 
    ON (teams.team_id = players.team_id AND teams.season = players.season ) 
WHERE players.season = '2015/2016' 
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: I want to display players records, but player rows don't heave team_name values. I want all player statistics from players table and team_names from teams table where team_id and season are the same in boths tables.

Comment: That's why you suppose to get team_name from teams table you joining (teams.team_name) but as I said if you don't want the records with team_name = null to be shown use INNER JOIN to be sure player is assigned to the existing team